# .html() loses angular scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I try to append an HTML to another element using jquery's `html()`. I lose the ability to `ng-click`. Here is a rough description of my code. For example I have a controller called `testController`

```
angular.module("test")
.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", 
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        var systemMessage = "<div><span><\/span><\/div>";

        $scope.appendHtml = function () {
            systemMessage.find("span").html('<button ng-click="highlightQuestion(id)">go to</button>');
        }

        $scope.highlightQuestion = function (id) {
            console.log(id);
        }

    }]);
```

Once the HTML becomes rendered, when I try to click the button, nothing happens. What I would have expected was it will be able to access `highlightQuestion` function since in my code `systemMessage` was appended to the div that is controlled by `testController`. Anyone have any thoughts on how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)** service. Inject it into the `controller` and use

```
$scope.appendHtml = function () {
   var span = systemMessage.find("span");
   span.html('<button ng-click="highlightQuestion(id)">go to</button>');
   $compile(span)(scope);
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick reply. Can you show me a snippet on how to use `$compile` with this?

Comment: The button was not appended but the container was rendered. Will try without the `contents()` call